# Yii2 - Save and display DateTime in different formats

Tags: php, yii2, datetime-format

I need save attribute "created_at" in MySQL formatt "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", but display in php format "d-m-Y".

It´s works fine in create scenario but when i update any attribute and save, its overwrite "created_at" and set like "0000-00-00 00:00:00" automatically in DB.
I use two functions in the model **beforeValidade()** and **afterFind()**.

**common\models\Oficios.php**

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    if ($this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_CREATE){
        $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }else {
        $this->created_at = $this->created_at;
    }

    return parent::beforeValidate(); 
}

public function afterFind ()
{
    // convert to display format
    $this->created_at = strtotime ($this->created_at);
    $this->created_at = date ('d-m-Y', $this->created_at);

    parent::afterFind ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `TimestampBehavior` in your data model? You could handle this issue easily with this behavior (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-behaviors#using-timestamp-behavior) without doing manually.

As it is stated in the documentation:

> This behavior supports automatically updating the timestamp attributes
>   of an Active Record model anytime the model is saved via insert(),
>   update() or save() method

Comment: happens the same, when i use afterFind() :(

Comment: the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...
        array('created_at','default',
              'value'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
              'setOnEmpty'=>false,'on'=>'insert')
    );
}
```

and eliminate the function "beforeValidate"

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks, but happens the same. i think the problem is with the function afterFind().

Answer (score 0):

You always can use behaviors. This is more clean and advanced way. You can control all events that model has. Here is example:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::class,
                'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
                'updatedAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
                'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ],
            [
                'class' => AttributeBehavior::class,
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_FIND => 'created_at'
                ],
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    // Any Format you want
                    return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($model->created_at));
                }
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: the result is the same when i change to `` return date("d-m-Y", strtotime($model->created_at)); ``

Comment: Try out this one. It should help you

Comment: no, because in this way every time i make "update" the "created_at" will be replaced.

Comment: the only way I found, is formatting date to "d-m-Y" in own view (e.g. in _DetailView_ or _GridView_).
I think is not a best solution but...

Answer (score 0):

If created_at is saved as Unix like use `Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at,'d-m-Y')`